# Change textNode value

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

Is there any way to change the value of a DOM textNode in web browser?

I specifically want to see if I can **change** the existing node, rather than **creating** a new one.

To clarify, I need to do this with Javascript. All text in the browser is stored in #textNodes which are children of other HTML nodes, but cannot have child nodes of their own.

As [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5023/ash) answered [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/680447), content can be changed by setting the **nodeValue** property of these Objects.

Comment: Example of HTML & what you would like to change? Do you want to do it using javascript?

Comment: During my research on same question, I found out that [Mozilla Developer Network raises a security notice about `innerHTML` usage, and favors `textContent` usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Security_considerations). Using `textContent` works fine for me.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

If you have a specific node (of type #text) and want to change its value you can use the [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue) property:

```
node.nodeValue="new value";
```

Note:

innerText (and <del>possibly</del> textContent) will return/set both the current node and all descendent nodes text, and so may not be the behaviour you want/expect.

Comment: Yes, nodeValue is perfect for this. innerText and textContent differ in this regard: IE (who created innerText) doesn't support it on #text nodes (since there are no child nodes to textify), whereas textContent was meant to be used on both #Element AND #text nodes.

Comment: There's also ‘data’ as a short synonym for ‘nodeValue’ on Text (as well as CDATASection and Comment).

Comment: nodeValue is the one I needed. For some reason I thought it was read-only, but seems to work on FF3 and IE7. Thanks!

Comment: @petermeissner: This answers the question perfectly, so your downvote is completely unwarranted.

Comment: Works not always .. "When nodeValue is defined to be null, setting it has no effect."  .. I opted in that case for "textContent" ... setting it updated also the value for "innerText"

Comment: Note that if you are trying to set the "text" of an element (and not a text node), you might have to `element.insertBefore(document.createTextNode('text'), null)` instead of `element.nodeValue='text'` if the node has no text children.

Comment: This did not work for me, but `node.innerText = "new value"` did.

Answer (score -16):

I believe innerHTML is used for this... Then again, that isn't W3C approved... but it works...

```
node.innerHTML="new value";
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution. nodeValue does not let me replace the content of the element

Comment: You should *never* use `innerHTML` as it treats code as text both in reading *and* writing.

Comment: @petermeissner: This doesn't answer question. You have to set `nodeValue` on the text node, not its parent element.