# Adding html at a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div with contenteditable:

```
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">This is an example</div>
```

Using `innerHTML`, I get "This is an example".

Now at 7th position (right after "is"), I want to add a html (`<span class="yup">NOT</span>`) to give the following (either using `click`, `focus` what-not)

```
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">This is <span class="yup">NOT</span> an example</div>
```

Knowing the caret position and innerHTML, how would I add a html into it?

I thought about using `substr` then `.html(content)`, but that's replacing the whole content and I want to avoid it. I want to simply add a content directly at a specific position.

For example: Replacing the whole content and what I DON'T want to do.

```
c = c.substr(0, e) + '<span class="yup">NOT</span>' + c.substr(e)';
$("div.example").html(c);
```

Instead of replacing it, I want to just "inject" it.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Added an example that I tried (which replaces the whole content and what I don't want to do ).

Comment: I'm not sure you can "inject" into the middle of a text node.  I think you would likely need to replace...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change textNode value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680431/change-textnode-value)

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way of inserting it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in JavaScript, you can't modify the content without creating a new one.

This is about as close as you can get (on par with `substr` and `substring`).

```js
// Store the new data
var newOutput = " <span class='yup'>NOT</span> ";

// Get a reference to the target div
var theDiv = $("div.example");

// Split the current content of the div where there are spaces
// and return the individual words into a new array
var words = theDiv.text().split(/\s+/g);

// Inject the right pieces of the array along with spaces and the new content
// into the div
theDiv.html(words[0] + " " + words[1] + newOutput + words[2] + " " + words[3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">This is an example</div>
```

But, if you have the opportunity to generate the content of the `div` from pure JavaScript, then you can inject the correct string just once, like this (run this snippet several times so that you can see the div's content change as various random numbers are generated).

```js
// Store the new data
var output1 = "This is an example.";
var output2 = "This is <span class='yup'>NOT</span> an example.";

// Get a reference to the target div
var theDiv = $("div.example");


// Inject the correct string into the div based on some criteria
var x = Math.random() > .5;
x === true ? theDiv.html(output1) : theDiv.html(output2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">This is an example</div>
```

Comment: I see that it still replaces the whole content instead of injecting it at a specific location.

Comment: Again, you can't inject a string into another string without replacing the entire original string. No matter how you slice it (no pun intended), modifying the text content of the `div` will require the old string to go away and a new string to take its place.

Comment: Mhmm, I understand. Looking into a different method. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are attempting and why replacing a string is not acceptable for you?

Comment: Sorry for lack of description. As users add inputs (could be couple paragraphs), I want to be able to add certain html markups into the existing string instead of replacing it. My logic is that replacing is not as efficient as "injecting" it. But now that I am thinking, maybe it is not such a bad idea.

Comment: As we've said, you can't actually "inject" a string into another string without creating a new string. Replacing one string with another is nothing (performance wise). Don't waste one moment of your time worrying about that. The real concern is the repaint/reflow of the document in the browser.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the reply. =) Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the HTML-string of an element without setting the whole content. I would recommend putting the `<span class="yup">NOT</span>` already in place but making it invisible with CSS. Then if it is toggled you just make it visible with Javascript.